# Compiling x86 Assembly Code on Mac using NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am an absolute beginner to Assembly and I am trying to compile a simple .asm file using NASM on Mac.

Here's the code although I doubt its any help

```
global _start
_start:
    mov eax, 1
    move ebx, 42
```

NASM gives me the following message everytime

```
anonymous@MacBook-Pro x86 % nasm -f macho32 example1.asm
example1.asm:5: error: parser: instruction expected
```

Can someone give me an example of how to compile and link it correctly?

Comment: Your example only has 4 lines, and the first error is on line 5.  Although `move` isn't a valid mnemonic, probably you mean `mov`, and removed a blank line so your [mcve] doesn't match the error message.

Comment: (But note, if you're about to run an `int 0x80` instruction, a Linux 32-bit `_exit` system call, MacOS passes args differently to 32-bit system calls (on the stack), and modern MacOS might not support 32-bit syscalls.  It might also use different call numbers; I know it does for 64-bit `syscall`.  Probably best to find a 64-bit MacOS asm tutorial unless your Mac / MacOS is old enough to support 32-bit executables.  A good tutorial will also show you how to link, run, and use a debugger.)